# Twitter external login is pending forever on .net web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, twitter-oauth

I'm facing a weird issue with the `Twitter external login` of `Asp.Net Web Api`.

I get an endless pending request when trying to redirect to Twitter screen (so I get a blank loading page), any of you had that issue before?

Everything is ok when I use my `MVC` site but it fails for Twitter when I use the API while Facebook login works fine on both site and API.